# "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_support_default_root'" while trying to use TkTreectrl

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Every time I attempt to run the following line:

```
self.databox = treectrl.MultiListbox(self.balance_info.portal, columns=('Date', 'Amount', 'Angle', 'RPM'))
```

I get the error:

```
`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1537, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\buntroh\Desktop\Balance\Balance Docs.py", line 141, in <lambda>
    ttk.Button(self.parent, text="Load Balance Report", command=lambda: self.balance_report()
  File "C:\Users\buntroh\Desktop\Balance\Balance Docs.py", line 319, in balance_report
    self.databox = treectrl.MultiListbox(self.balance_info.portal, columns=('Date', 'Amount', 'Angle', 'RPM'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\TkTreectrl\MultiListbox.py", line 50, in __init__
    Treectrl.__init__(self, master, showroot=showroot, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\TkTreectrl\Treectrl.py", line 484, in __init__
    if tkinter._support_default_root:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_support_default_root'`
```

I looked at the `Tkinter.py` file in my Python folder and found a variable called `_support_default_root` so I have no idea why `TkTreectrl` is unable to find it.

Minimal Example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import TkTreectrl as treectrl
import sqlite3

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    mlb = treectrl.MultiListbox(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you importing tkinter? Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that has the absolute fewest lines possible to generate this error?

Comment: @BryanOakley `import Tkinter as tk`, and `import TkTreectrl as treectrl`

Comment: @BryanOakley I put a minimal example in the question.

Comment: Is your script (or some other script you've written) named `tkinter.py`, by any chance?  That would shadow the real Tkinter module, containing the definition of `_support_default_root`.

Comment: @jasonharper Nope, nothing else is. Besides, everything else running on `tkinter`, i.e. the whole GUI works fine up until the point where the `TkTreectrl` module is used

Comment: Using TkTreectrl requires TkinterTreectrl to run with python / tkinter. Have a look at: http://tkintertreectrl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @R4PH3L Hmm thanks for that. Looks like I only had TkinterTreectrl installed. I installed TkTreectrl as the website said and extracted the .zip archive into my tcl folder. I also reinstalled TkTreectrl for good measure, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @RBuntu can you please also post the versions of both framework and wrapper you used and installed?

Comment: @R4PH43L I installed `tktreectrl-2.4.1-86_64`, my python 2.7 is 64 bit. Also I have `TkinterTreectrl-2.0.1` installed. I've decided to just use `tk.Labels` arranged in a grid for my project for now.

Comment: @RBuntu : how did you install TkinterTreectrl? are you running multiple versions of python on your machine? If so, please follow the instructions for the installation inside the readme of Tkintertreectrl for multiple python versions installed on one machine. The error currently looks for me like the tkintertreectrl is not getting the proper environment on necessary tktreectrl / tcl / tk bindings.

Comment: @R4PH43L Hi, I only have Python 2.7 installed on my machine, I have never installed or downloaded any other versions of Python.

Comment: @RBuntu Please open a ticket at: https://sourceforge.net/p/tkintertreectrl/tickets/

Comment: @RBuntu Does your example produce similar output? Just looked into tkintertreectrls docs and there a Multilistbox is not initialized with the columns but configured with them afterwards...